# Uploaded photos not showing on Timeline

Tags: facebook, photos, facebook-timeline

I have some problems with some photos that I have uploaded on a Facebook Page.
Although they upload correctly, they do not appear on my Page Timeline even if they have a date on them. This does not happen to every album from the Facebook Page.

They are displayed in the News Feed but there is a problem there as well, because Facebook is showing like I have uploaded an entire album every time I upload a single image.

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: And the question is...

Comment: The question is:
How can I make them appear on my Tmieline?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/KnownIssues/posts/459865334025169

Comment: Can you please send the URL of the FB page so that i can have the look, possibly there is an issue with the dates you have entered for the creation or something for the page.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by going to the Album you want to post. Click on the gear symbol on right hand top corner-click on "Get link"- copy and paste the link in your Status and post.

Comment: The only thing the link does is add the entire album not the "recently added photos" as it use to do.